# How do I make terraform skip that block while creating multiple resources in loop from a CSV file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hi I am trying to create a Terraform script which will take inputs from the user in the form of a CSV file and create multiple Azure resources. 
For example if the user wants to create: ResourceGroup>Vnet>Subnet in bulk, he will provide input in CSV format as below:

```
  resourcegroup,RG_location,RG_tag,domainname,DNS_Zone_tag,virtualnetwork,VNET_location,addressspace
  csvrg1,eastus2,Terraform RG,test.sd,Terraform RG,csvvnet1,eastus2,10.0.0.0/16,Terraform VNET,subnet1,10.0.0.0/24
  csvrg2,westus,Terraform RG2,test2.sd,Terraform RG2,csvvnet2,westus,172.0.0.0/8,Terraform VNET2,subnet1,171.0.0.0/24
```

I have written the following working main.tf file:

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {

version = "=1.43.0"

subscription_id = var.subscription
tenant_id = var.tenant
client_id = var.client
client_secret = var.secret
}

#Decoding the csv file
locals {
  vmcsv = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/computelanding.csv"))
}



# Create a resource group if it doesn’t exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myterraformgroup" {
  count = length(local.vmcsv)
  name =  local.vmcsv[count.index].resourcegroup
  location =  local.vmcsv[count.index].RG_location

    tags = {
        environment = local.vmcsv[count.index].RG_tag
    }
}

# Create a DNS Zone
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "dnsp-private" {
  count = 1
  name                = local.vmcsv[count.index].domainname
  resource_group_name = local.vmcsv[count.index].resourcegroup

  depends_on            = [azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup]

    tags = {
        environment = local.vmcsv[count.index].DNS_Zone_tag
    }
}

To be continued....
```

The issue I am facing here what is in the second resource group, the user don't want a resource type, suppose the user want to skip the DNS zone in the resource group csvrg2. **How do I make terraform skip that block ?**

Edit: What I am trying to achieve is "based on some condition in the CSV file, not to create azurerm_dns_zone resource for the resource group csvrg2"

I have provided an example of the CSV file, how it may look like below:

```
  resourcegroup,RG_location,RG_tag,DNS_required,domainname,DNS_Zone_tag,virtualnetwork,VNET_location,addressspace
  csvrg1,eastus2,Terraform RG,1,test.sd,Terraform RG,csvvnet1,eastus2,10.0.0.0/16,Terraform VNET,subnet1,10.0.0.0/24
  csvrg2,westus,Terraform RG2,0,test2.sd,Terraform RG2,csvvnet2,westus,172.0.0.0/8,Terraform VNET2,subnet1,171.0.0.0/24
```

Comment: "based on some condition, not to create azurerm_dns_zone resource for csvrg2" This is my requirement. There should be some condition in the CSV that makes it skip a particular block. I tried this (local.vmcsv[count.index].domainname == 0 ? null : local.vmcsv[count.index].domainname) but terraform is taking "null" as the name and not a null value.

Comment: Please look into for_each instead of using count, [ for i in ... ] to create a list which can be used to eliminate those to skip, conditional expression (https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). Since the goal is not clear, specifics are missing, only possible to provide where to look potentially.

Comment: The ask is simple: The User will use one CSV file as input to provision multiple resources in Azure. At the backend will be a TF script.

The user may create multiple resource groups with different types of resources in each group. One resource group may have all network resources, other resource group may have storage resources. How do I achieve that ?

As per my understanding, as we are using a single CSV file, which will provide "key"= "value" parameter, I need some way to skip specific keys which represents a block in the TF script.

Comment: You need to be specific about the condition logic to identify if to skip a line in the csv (csvrg2). What is the criteria to decide if to create azurerm_dns_zone or not. In which sentence in your question specifies it? You keep saying "want to skip" "on some condition" but never mentioned what the condition is.

Comment: Please check my post. I mentioned sush a condition in  CSV header as `DNS_required`. If the value is 1, it will create, if 0, it will skip.
But I am not sure how to make that condition work. Else if I leaving null values for DNS work, that will also do.

Answer (score 0):

you had already the right thought in your mind using the `depends_on` function. Although, you're using a `count` inside, which causes from my understanding, that once the first resource[0] is created, Terraform sees the dependency as solved and goes ahead as well.

I found this post with a workaround which you might be able to try:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15285#issuecomment-447971852

That basically tells us to create a `null_resource` like in that example:

```
variable "instance_count" {
  default = 0
}

resource "null_resource" "a" {
  count = var.instance_count
}

resource "null_resource" "b" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.a]
}
```

In your example, it might look like this:

```
# Create a resource group if it doesn’t exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myterraformgroup" {
  count = length(local.vmcsv)
  name =  local.vmcsv[count.index].resourcegroup
  location =  local.vmcsv[count.index].RG_location

    tags = {
        environment = local.vmcsv[count.index].RG_tag
    }
}

# Create a DNS Zone
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "dnsp-private" {
  count = 1
  name                = local.vmcsv[count.index].domainname
  resource_group_name = local.vmcsv[count.index].resourcegroup

  depends_on            = null_resource.example

    tags = {
        environment = local.vmcsv[count.index].DNS_Zone_tag
    }
}

resource "null_resource" "example" {
  ...
  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup[length(local.vmcsv)]]
}
```

or depending on your Terraform version (0.12+ which you're using guessing your syntax)

```
# Create a resource group if it doesn’t exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myterraformgroup" {
  count = length(local.vmcsv)
  name =  local.vmcsv[count.index].resourcegroup
  location =  local.vmcsv[count.index].RG_location

    tags = {
        environment = local.vmcsv[count.index].RG_tag
    }
}

# Create a DNS Zone
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "dnsp-private" {
  count = 1
  name                = local.vmcsv[count.index].domainname
  resource_group_name = local.vmcsv[count.index].resourcegroup

  depends_on            = [azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup[length(local.vmcsv)]]

    tags = {
        environment = local.vmcsv[count.index].DNS_Zone_tag
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Greetings

Comment: While it creates the second resource group long with its resources, I need it to skip the DNS zone and other resources based on condition in the CSV

For the first RG: 
csvrg1>> DNS1 >> Vnet1 >> Subnet1 >> Firewall1
For the second RG
csvrg2 >> Vnet2>>Subnet2